# How do I get the domain name of the load balancer when I deploy Ingress ALB using helm and terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm deploying an EKS cluster and within that I'm deploying ALB based ingress controller.
I need to get the DNS of the load balancer so I can configure a CNAME in Route53.

```bash
...
resource "helm_release" "aws_lb_controller" {
  name              = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository        = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  chart             = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  namespace         = "kube-system"
  force_update      = "true"
  dependency_update = "true"
  depends_on = [ aws_iam_role.aws_lb_controller_role, null_resource.get_kubeconfig]
  # version           = "2.4.2" # current

  set {
...
...
...
}
...
```